# Array sorting problem(sort by price) in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, price

I am sorting item by price and alphabetically also.
It sorts alphabetically perfectly fine. It is sorting price Array but not printing objects according to sorted price. Everything is doing perfect in console.log but when I select price low to high option its doesn't make any changes to items, while its making in console.

```js
$(document.body).on('change', '#products-sorting', function() {

  var priceArr = [];
  var nameArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
    var price = $(tempArr[i]).find('.addToWishlist').data("price").replace("$", "");
    var name = $(tempArr[i]).find('.addToWishlist').data("name");
    priceArr.push(price)
    nameArr.push(name);
  }
  //sort by Price
  for (var n = 0; n < priceArr.length; n++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
      //sort price low to high
      if ($(this).val() === 'Price, low to high') {
        priceArr.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a - b
        })
      }
      //sort price high to low
      if ($(this).val() === 'Price, high to low') {
        priceArr.sort(function(a, b) {
          return b - a
        })
      }
      var price = $(tempArr[i]).find('.addToWishlist').data("price").replace("$", "");
      if (priceArr[n] == price)
        $("#product-items").append(tempArr[i])
    }
  }
  //console.log(priceArr)
  //sort Alphabetically
  for (var n = 0; n < nameArr.length; n++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
      //sort alphabetically A to Z 
      if ($(this).val() === 'Alphabetically, A to Z')
        nameArr.sort();
      //sort alphabetically Z to A
      if ($(this).val() === 'Alphabetically, Z to A') {
        nameArr.sort();
        nameArr.reverse()
      }
      var name = $(tempArr[i]).find('.addToWishlist').data("name");
      if (nameArr[n] == name)
        $("#product-items").append(tempArr[i])
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-box" class="clearfix">
  <label for="products">Sort by</label>
  <select name="products" id="products-sorting">
    <option value="Featured">Featured</option>
    <option value="Alphabetically, A to Z">Alphabetically, A to Z</option>
    <option value="Alphabetically, Z to A">Alphabetically, Z to A</option>
    <option value="Price, low to high">Price, low to high</option>
    <option value="Price, high to low">Price, high to low</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `tempArr`?

Comment: Why do you have loops around your sorting? You should sort the array once, then loop over the result to update the table.

Comment: I have array of object containing html content(tempArr). thats why I need loops.

Comment: From that array i am retriving price and name to make saparate arrays

Comment: But you're sorting the same array every time through the loop. The sort isn't going to change.

Comment: How can I sort it easily?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do your sorting inside loops. Just sort `tempArr` rather than copying to `priceArr` and `nameArr`. Then you can append `tempArr` to the container to display it in the sorted order.

```js
$(document.body).on('change', '#products-sorting', function() {

  function getPrice(el) {
    return parseFloat($(el).find('.addToWishlist').data("price").replace("$", ""));
  }

  function getName(el) {
    return $(el).find('.addToWishlist').data("name");
  }

  switch ($(this).val()) {
    //sort price low to high
    case 'Price, low to high':
      tempArr.sort((a, b) => getPrice(a) - getPrice(b));
      break;
      //sort price high to low
    case 'Price, high to low':
      tempArr.sort((a, b) => getPrice(b) - getPrice(a));
      break;
    case 'Alphabetically, A to Z':
      tempArr.sort((a, b) => getName(a).localeCompare(getName(b)));
      break;
    case 'Alphabetically, Z to A':
      tempArr.sort((a, b) => getName(b).localeCompare(getName(a)));
      break;
  }
  
  $("#product-items").empty().append(tempArr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-box" class="clearfix">
  <label for="products">Sort by</label>
  <select name="products" id="products-sorting">
    <option value="Featured">Featured</option>
    <option value="Alphabetically, A to Z">Alphabetically, A to Z</option>
    <option value="Alphabetically, Z to A">Alphabetically, Z to A</option>
    <option value="Price, low to high">Price, low to high</option>
    <option value="Price, high to low">Price, high to low</option>
  </select>
</div>
```